# Add dynamic progress console to MVC razor page

Tags: c#, .net, razor, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I am trying to create a Razor website that is creating a background worker that calls a script on the server-side. After that, I am trying to show worker progress with a dynamic update whenever a user will open the worker details page. So it's something similar to TeamCity Build Log when you can see how CI is progressing (build, tests etc.). My worker on the background will create a text log file where he saves progress. I need to connect it somehow to razor page view.

[image: rogr]

My problem is that I cannot find any up to date tutorials of adding a dynamic "console" view to razor view. I tried to do it with the creation of worker log table in the database and connect it to razor view but it sounds like a bit overcomplication of a simple task.

```
<textarea class="form-control" wrap="soft" readonly>
  @foreach (var log in Model.WorkerLogs)
  {
      <partial name="_WorkerLog" model="log" />
  }
</textarea>
```